# PHP Foreach distinct the value, sum the value, group by and show it on echo

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I have an array json data, I want to sum the value and show it on echo with distinct, I have read another thread about this but cannot figure it out on my case.

JSON :

```
{
    "perusahaan": {
        "nomorLaporan": "blabla",
        "posisiDataTerakhir": "201912",
        "tanggalPermintaan": "blabla",
        "fasilitas": {
            "suratBerharga": [],
            "kreditPembiayan": [
                {
                    "ljk": "510",
                    "ljkKet": "BANK NATIONALNOBU",
                    "jumlahHariTunggakan": "0",
                    "nilaiProyek": "20000000000",
                    "plafonAwal": "20000000000",
                    "plafon": "20000000000"
                },
                {
                    "ljk": "503",
                    "ljkKet": "BANK NATIONALNOBU",
                    "jumlahHariTunggakan": "0",
                    "nilaiProyek": "15000000000",
                    "plafonAwal": "15000000000",
                    "plafon": "15000000000"
                },
                {
                    "ljk": "563",
                    "ljkKet": "BCA",
                    "jumlahHariTunggakan": "0",
                    "nilaiProyek": "15000000000",
                    "plafonAwal": "15000000000",
                    "plafon": "15000000000"
                },
                {
                    "ljk": "509",
                     "ljkKet": "BCA",
                      "jumlahHariTunggakan": "0",
                      "nilaiProyek": "15000000000",
                      "plafonAwal": "15000000000",
                     "plafon": "15000000000"
                 }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

PHP :

```
$summedvalueshere=0;
$string = file_get_contents('ideb/NPWP.txt');
$json_a = json_decode($string, TRUE);
 foreach ($mainjson['perusahaan']['fasilitas']['kreditPembiayan'] as $v) {
 $summedvalueshere+=$v['plafonAwal'];
 echo $v['ljkKet']." = ".$summedvalueshere;
}
```

But it shows :

```
BANK NATIONALNOBU = 20000000000
BANK NATIONALNOBU = 35000000000
BCA = 50000000000
BCA = 65000000000
```

What I expect:

```
BANK NATIONALNOBU = 35000000000

BCA = 30000000000
```

Any idea how to solve it ? thanks in advance..

Comment: just continually add it inside the loop `variable += value here`

Comment: it shows :

BANK NATIONALNOBU = 20000000000
BANK NATIONALNOBU = 35000000000
BCA = 50000000000
BCA = 65000000000

Comment: Of course it will show you the summary each time after adding the value from the next set cause you echo inside the loop. If you want to show the sum only once, make the echo outside of the loop.

Comment: If I echo outside the loop  : BCA = 65000000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
$string = file_get_contents('ideb/NPWP.txt');    
$mainjson = json_decode($string, TRUE);

//create an array to store the total values
$value_array = array(); 

//go over each item in the json
foreach ($mainjson['perusahaan']['fasilitas']['kreditPembiayan'] as $v) {

        //if an item with same name has been found add this value to it
    if(array_key_exists($v['ljkKet'], $value_array)){ 
        $value_array[$v['ljkKet']] += $v['plafonAwal'];
    }else{
        //else creat a new element in the array with current value

        $value_array[$v['ljkKet']] = $v['plafonAwal'];
    }

}
// display the results
// for each item in value array
foreach($value_array as $key => $value){
    // print the name and the value
    echo $key.' = '.$value.'<br>';
}
```

Basically create another array that stores the valuse and adds them as it finds more. then go over the array and echo the results out. I tired putiing in comments to help you understand it better. If you have any questions let me know.

---

**EDIT:**

In answer to your comments. You could split the functionality up into different functions and then call them for differnt values. see code below:

```
$string = file_get_contents('ideb/NPWP.txt');        
$mainjson = json_decode($string, TRUE);

//setting main json path to branch_array, easyier to read.
$branch_array = $mainjson['perusahaan']['fasilitas']['kreditPembiayan'];

//sum the differnt values
//plafonAwal
$plafonAwal_array = sum_data($branch_array, 'plafonAwal'); 
//nilaiProyek
$nilaiProyek_array = sum_data($branch_array, 'nilaiProyek'); 
//jumlahHariTunggakan
$jumlahHariTunggakan_array = sum_data($branch_array, 'jumlahHariTunggakan'); 


//print the results
print_results($plafonAwal_array, 'plafonAwal');
echo '<br>';
print_results($nilaiProyek_array, 'nilaiProyek');
echo '<br>';
print_results($jumlahHariTunggakan_array, 'jumlahHariTunggakan');


// --- FUNCTIONS --- //
//add the values of specified key
function sum_data($data_array, $key_name){
    $value_array =array();

    foreach ($data_array as $v) {

        if(array_key_exists($v['ljkKet'], $value_array)){
            $value_array[$v['ljkKet']] += $v[$key_name];
        }else{

            $value_array[$v['ljkKet']] = $v[$key_name];
        }

    }

    return $value_array;
}

//function prints results of sums with a custom heading
function print_results($result_array, $heading=''){

    // if there is a heading print it out
    if($heading!=''){
        echo $heading.':<br>';
    }

    // display the results
    // for each item in $result_array
    foreach($result_array as $key => $value){

        echo $key.' = '.$value.'<br>';
    }

}
```

I split the functionality up into 2 different functions 1 adds the values the other one prints them out.

the output looks something like this:

```
plafonAwal:
BANK NATIONALNOBU = 35000000000
BCA = 30000000000

nilaiProyek:
BANK NATIONALNOBU = 35000000000
BCA = 30000000000

jumlahHariTunggakan:
BANK NATIONALNOBU = 0
BCA = 0
```

---

**Summary option:**

if you ment you would like asummary of the differnt locations you could use this code:

```
$string = file_get_contents('ideb/NPWP.txt');    
$mainjson = json_decode($string, TRUE);

//setting main json path to branch_array, easyier to read.
$branch_array = $mainjson['perusahaan']['fasilitas']['kreditPembiayan'];

//create the summary array
$summary_array = create_summary($branch_array);
//print the results
print_summary($summary_array);

// --- FUNCTIONS --- //
function create_summary($data_array){
    $value_array = array();
    foreach ($data_array as $v) {
        //if haven't done a row for this loication set up a new array with defaults set to 0
        if(!isset($value_array[$v['ljkKet']])){
            $value_array[$v['ljkKet']] = array( 
                'plafonAwal'=> 0,
                'nilaiProyek'=> 0, 
                'jumlahHariTunggakan'=> 0, 

            );
        }
        // add the values to existing values
        $value_array[$v['ljkKet']]['plafonAwal'] += $v['plafonAwal'];
        $value_array[$v['ljkKet']]['nilaiProyek'] += $v['nilaiProyek'];
        $value_array[$v['ljkKet']]['jumlahHariTunggakan'] += $v['jumlahHariTunggakan'];

    }

    return $value_array;
}

function print_summary($summary_array){

    foreach ($summary_array as $location => $data) {
        echo "Summary for {$location}:<br>
        plafonAwal: {$data['plafonAwal']}<br>
        nilaiProyek: {$data['nilaiProyek']}<br>
        jumlahHariTunggakan: {$data['jumlahHariTunggakan']} <br><br>
        ";
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Summary for BANK NATIONALNOBU:
plafonAwal: 35000000000
nilaiProyek: 35000000000
jumlahHariTunggakan: 0

Summary for BCA:
plafonAwal: 30000000000
nilaiProyek: 30000000000
jumlahHariTunggakan: 0
```

It's easy to change the formating of the summary. Just change the echo in the print_summary function

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works ..

what I did not expect is this part  $value_array[$v['ljkKet']];

Comment: @Maulanaiman do you understand what it is doing? or should i explain it some more?

Comment: How if I want to sum another value like $v['nilaiProyek'] ?

Comment: I mean sum $v['nilaiProyek'] and $v['plafonAwal'] also show the value of $v['jumlahHariTunggakan'] inside echo..

Comment: I really appreciate your answer,but I forgot to show the goals, what I want is 

BANK NATIONALNOBU = 35000000000, nilaiProyek = 35000000000, jumlahHariTunggakan : 0

BCA = 30000000000, nilaiProyek = 30000000000, jumlahHariTunggakan : 0

I'm sorry for bothering you..

Comment: i added a summary option. is that what you wanted?